# ajax new record count notification in php

Tags: php, ajax

iam doing a page in php that if any new record is entered it will notify the users screen with the new record count. Following is the code i did for the same, but its not working fine. Can u pls suggest me as of what iam doing wrong...

```
 alert.php

 <?php
 require("config.php");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marketing_tend_corr");
 $res = mysql_num_rows($result);
 echo $res;
 ?>




 index.php
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <?php 
 define('BASEPATH', true);
 require("config.php");
 ?>
 <script>

 var count_cases = -1;
 setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "alert.php",
    success : function(response){
        if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response) echo $count_cases);
        count_cases = response;
    }
});
 },1000);

 </script>
```

Comment: I think you want to **alert** and not **echo**

Comment: alert is working fine here but i need as an echo of count of new message.

Comment: @SujithNair  but you couldn' write php code like this inside javascript

Comment: i know, but is there a way that i can show the count of the new records?

Comment: This is working fine actually, but i need to show/print the number of new records........... if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response) alert('new record on tender marketing');

Comment: alert(response) too hard to use or?

Comment: Console it or append a paragraph with the body to show that count like $('body').append('<p>' + response+'</p>');

Comment: @Naruto, yeah i need to record it or show somewhere on the count on my new records. That's the issue..:)

Comment: html= <div id='total_count'></div>  --- jquery: $("#total_count').html(response); Something like this?

Comment: Its not working. blank output is coming.

Comment: Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code is not going to work in Javascript:

```
if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response) echo $count_cases);
```

This line of code contains php code (echo $count_cases) which is server side code.

I've changed the code a bit and replaced the number of records by returning a random value.

// alert.php

```
<?php

echo rand(1, 1000000);
```

//index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "alert.php",
                success : function(response){                        
                    $("body").html(response);
                }
            });
        },1000);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check the index.php file in your browser to see the random numbers being returned. This random number should in your case become the result of your 'mysql_num_rows' function.